# How to view where the ETH went to from a smart contract? (rinkeby network)

Tags: rinkeby

Below is a smart contract address: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x5f340edfd1c7b6a7f282f29f3fb0fda51df28af9

It shows that 2.55 ETH has been received. And then 3 function calls have been made. The final balance shows up as 0.00975. How do I find out where the smart contract sent the ETH to?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Rinkeby test network’s Etherscan doesn’t appear to track internal transactions. If you compare the testnet version of Etherscan to the production version of Etherscan, you see different menus — notably the ones related to tracking internal transactions.

I’ve attached comparisons between your contract on the testnet, and the interface of a random contract on the mainnet. As you can see, Etherscan on Rinkeby clearly doesn’t show the same menus and the same options. Unfortunately.

[image: Rinkeby Etherscan]
[image: Mainnet Etherscan]

Since internal transactions aren’t tracked by the blockchain by default — you have to actually tally each one as it goes off — it’s possible that Etherscan simply didn’t start tracking them early enough and now tracking them would result in inconsistent data.